# HTML tags in Dotnetnuke not working

Tags: header, tags, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I've been trying to add HTML tag to the page with no success. The code I use is:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.PreRender
    Dim defaultPage As CDefault = TryCast(Me.Page, CDefault)
    defaultPage.HtmlAttributes.Add("xmlns:og", "http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/")
    defaultPage.HtmlAttributes.Add("xmlns:fb", "http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml")
End Sub
```

And the resulting page should contain:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

I debugged the code and it adds the tags to the page object, but eventually the resulting page tags are missing. Can anybody advise what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the internationalization features in DNN overwrite it since it adds the culture of the site (or at least what the user set) for example < html lang="en-US" > (this is a guess I haven't traced through it)

A simple fix might be to add your html tag to the 'skin name'.doctype.xml file in the skin directory (make sure a valid doctype is defined before it.  That may do it